# Linhas no export excel

Tags: php, html, microsoft-excel

Estou exportando uma listagem para excel, mas quando abro o excel ele vem sem as divisórias.

```
<?php

require_once '../../classes/xajax.inc.php';

$db = new SqlSrv();

//$sql = "SELECT * FROM cad_pessoas WHERE matricula = '$matricula'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT p.id_pessoa,
p.matricula,
p.nome,
p.tipo_pessoa,
p.saldo_conta_corrente,
p.saldo_comprometido,
TRUNCATE(saldo_conta_corrente + saldo_comprometido, 2) AS saldo_total
FROM cad_pessoas p) AS tbl
    WHERE (saldo_conta_corrente != 0 OR saldo_comprometido != 0 OR saldo_total != 0)";

$resultado = $db->select($sql);

/*
* Criando e exportando planilhas do Excel
* /
*/
// Definimos o nome do arquivo que será exportado
$arquivo = 'planilha.xls';
// Criamos uma tabela HTML com o formato da planilha
$html = '';
$html .= '<table>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td colspan="3">Planilha teste</tr>';
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td><b>Matricula</b></td>';
$html .= '<td><b>Nome</b></td>';
$html .= '<td><b>Saldo Conta Corrente</b></td>';
$html .= '<td><b>Saldo Comprometido</b></td>';
$html .= '<td><b>Saldo Total</b></td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
    foreach ($resultado as $resultados){
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$resultados["matricula"].'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$resultados["nome"].'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$resultados["saldo_conta_corrente"].'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$resultados["saldo_comprometido"].'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$resultados["saldo_total"].'</td>';
    }
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '</table>';
// Configurações header para forçar o download
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
// Envia o conteúdo do arquivo
echo $html;
exit;
```

O exportar está funcionando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quero que fique com as bordas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou colocando um `border="1"` na `<table>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sam respondeu a pergunta.

```
<table border="1">


</table>
```